# How to check if SQLite Database exists and then create it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite

I have data in a SQLite Database. But I can not be sure that it will always be there. So when I start my Program I first want to check if the SQLite Database exists and when not I want to create one with the DbSet's I already have in my DbContext.

```
public class MaintenanceDB : DbContext
{
    public MaintenanceDB() : base (new SQLiteConnection(new 
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = "data.sqlite"}.ConnectionString), true)
     { 
     }
     public DbSet<MaintenanceEntry> MaintenanceEntries { get; set; }
     public DbSet<ModuleEntry> ModuleEntries { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<MaintenanceEntry>().ToTable("some Table");
         modelBuilder.Entity<ModuleEntry>().ToTable("some Table");
     }

}
```

When I delete my SQLite Database and startup my Program again then I want my SQLite Database to be created.

Comment: Could you not just check if the `sqlite` file is present and if not create it new?

Comment: And how do I create a new one? plus when I do this in the constructor it already tries to read the db

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292880/create-sqlite-database-and-table/15292958)

Comment: Here's a link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159790/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-database-exists-c-sharp]
Hope this will help!

Comment: what do I have to change in my code? So i can still use it from outside

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MaintenanceDB" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

```
public class MaintenanceDB : DbContext
{
    public MaintenanceDB() : base ("Name=MaintenanceDB")
```

And try the solutions below:

```
var context = new MaintenanceDB();
if (!context.Database.Exists())
    context.Database.Create();
```

Or

```
var context = new MaintenanceDB();
context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Or create an initializer class as below:

```
// public class ContentInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseAlways <MaintenanceDB>
// public class ContentInitializer: CreateDatabaseIfNotExists <MaintenanceDB>
public class ContentInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges <MaintenanceDB>
```

And put this at the beginning of the application.

```
Database.SetInitializer (new ContentInitializer ());
```

Comment: When I try to delete the data.sqlite and then call `var context = new MaintenanceDB()` I already get an error because the data.sqlite does not exists.

Comment: I do not have the function SetInitializer

Comment: Create a connection string in app.config and call the MaintenanceDB constructor base by passing the name.